# expected a value of type 1Animation<double>1, but got one of type 'Null'

Tags: flutter, animation, null, nullable, flutter-getx

The following is my auth screen,  `authentication.dart` code:

```
class AuthenticationScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthenticationScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      // resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  const Color.fromRGBO(215, 117, 255, 1).withOpacity(0.5),
                  const Color.fromRGBO(255, 188, 117, 1).withOpacity(0.9),
                ],
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                stops: const [0, 1],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              height: deviceSize.height,
              width: deviceSize.width,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 94.0),
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(-8 * pi / 180)
                        ..translate(-10.0),
                      // ..translate(-10.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: Colors.deepOrange.shade900,
                        boxShadow: const [
                          BoxShadow(
                            blurRadius: 8,
                            color: Colors.black26,
                            offset: Offset(0, 2),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        'Welcome!',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Theme.of(context)
                              .textSelectionTheme
                              .selectionColor,
                          fontSize: 50,
                          fontFamily: 'Anton',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: deviceSize.width > 600 ? 2 : 1,
                    child: AuthCard(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthCard extends StatelessWidget {
  AuthCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static AuthCard instance = Get.find();
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    var _authMode = AuthController.instance.authMode;
    var _isLoading = AuthController.instance.isLoading;
    final Map<String, String> _authData = {
      'email': '',
      'password': '',
    };
    final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
    AnimationController? _controller;
    Animation<Offset>? _slideAnimation;
    Animation<double>? _opacityAnimation;

    void _switchAuthMode() {
      if (_authMode!.value == AuthMode.Login) {
        _authMode.value = AuthMode.Signup;
        _controller!.forward();
      } else {
        _authMode.value = AuthMode.Login;
        _controller!.reverse();
      }
    }

    void _showErrorDialog(String message) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('An Error Occurred!'),
          content: Text(message),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Okay'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    Future<void> _submit() async {
      if (!_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        // Invalid!
        return;
      }
      _formKey.currentState!.save();
      _isLoading!.value = true;

      try {
        if (_authMode!.value == AuthMode.Login) {
          // Log user in
          await AuthController.instance.login(
            _authData['email'] as String,
            _authData['password'] as String,
          );
        } else {
          // Sign user up
          await AuthController.instance.signup(
            _authData['email'] as String,
            _authData['password'] as String,
          );
        }
      } on HttpException catch (error) {
        var errorMessage = 'Authentication failed';

        if (error.toString().contains('EMAIL_EXISTS')) {
          errorMessage = 'This email address is already in use.';
        } else if (error.toString().contains('INVALID_EMAIL')) {
          errorMessage = 'This is not a valid email address';
        } else if (error.toString().contains('WEAK_PASSWORD')) {
          errorMessage = 'This password is too weak.';
        } else if (error.toString().contains('EMAIL_NOT_FOUND')) {
          errorMessage = 'Could not find a user with that email.';
        } else if (error.toString().contains('INVALID_PASSWORD')) {
          errorMessage = 'Invalid password.';
        }
        _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
      } catch (error) {
        var errorMessage =
            'Could not authenticate you. Please try again later.' +
                error.toString();
        _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
      }
    }

    return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      elevation: 8.0,
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
        height: _authMode!.value == AuthMode.Signup ? 320 : 260,
        //height: _heightAnimation.value.height,
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: _authMode.value == AuthMode.Signup ? 320 : 260),
        width: deviceSize.width * 0.75,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Obx(() => Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'E-Mail'),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                          return 'Invalid email!';
                        }
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _authData['email'] = value as String;
                      },
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                      obscureText: true,
                      controller: _passwordController,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 5) {
                          return 'Password is too short!';
                        }
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _authData['password'] = value as String;
                      },
                    ),
                    AnimatedContainer(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(
                        minHeight: _authMode.value == AuthMode.Signup ? 60 : 0,
                        maxHeight: _authMode.value == AuthMode.Signup ? 120 : 0,
                      ),
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                      curve: Curves.easeIn,
                      child: FadeTransition(
                        opacity: _opacityAnimation as Animation<double>,
                        child: SlideTransition(
                          position: _slideAnimation as Animation<Offset>,
                          child: TextFormField(
                            enabled: _authMode.value == AuthMode.Signup,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Confirm Password'),
                            obscureText: true,
                            validator: _authMode.value == AuthMode.Signup
                                ? (value) {
                                    if (value != _passwordController.text) {
                                      return 'Passwords do not match!';
                                    }
                                  }
                                : null,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    if (_isLoading!.value)
                      const CircularProgressIndicator()
                    else
                      Obx(() => ElevatedButton(
                            child: Text(_authMode.value == AuthMode.Login
                                ? 'LOGIN'
                                : 'SIGN UP'),
                            onPressed: _submit,
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                              ),
                              primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 8.0),
                              onPrimary: Theme.of(context)
                                  .primaryTextTheme
                                  .button!
                                  .color,
                            ),
                          )),
                    Obx(() => TextButton(
                          child: Text(
                              '${_authMode.value == AuthMode.Login ? 'SIGNUP' : 'LOGIN'} '),
                          onPressed: _switchAuthMode,
                          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 4),
                            tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                            textStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                          ),
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But when I trying to launch the application it shows the following error instead of the form widget:

[image]

I know the error comes from the following part of the code because when I comment out this part, the error message will gone but the functionality of app also gets affected.

```
        AnimatedContainer(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup ? 60 : 0,
            maxHeight: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup ? 120 : 0,
          ),
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          curve: Curves.easeIn,
          child: FadeTransition(
            opacity: _opacityAnimation as Animation<double>,
            child: SlideTransition(
              position: _slideAnimation as Animation<Offset>,
              child: TextFormField(
                enabled: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Confirm Password'),
                obscureText: true,
                validator: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup
                    ? (value) {
                        if (value != _passwordController.text) {
                          return 'Passwords do not match!';
                        }
                      }
                    : null,
              ),
            ),
          ),
   
 )
```

Please let me know what is the problem and how can I fix that?

PS: This code was working using statefull widget. But I tried to convert it to use GetX library with the modified version you can see above, and this problem happened after the modification.

EDIT: Regarthing to the `` answer, I checked the original code and found the previous part of code that I had deleted during my modification. But still don't know how exactly should I add it to my new(above) code?

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(
        milliseconds: 300,
      ),
    );
    _slideAnimation = Tween<Offset>(
      begin: const Offset(0, -1.5),
      end: const Offset(0, 0),
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _controller as Animation<double>,
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      ),
    );
    _opacityAnimation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _controller as Animation<double>,
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
      ),
    );
    // _heightAnimation.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've declared the _controller to be an AnimationController or null, and _slideAnimation as well as _opaciytAnimation an Animation or null.
You never instantiate them, correct? So they are still null.

```
AnimationController? _controller;
Animation<Offset>? _slideAnimation;
Animation<double>? _opacityAnimation;
```

Most likely you had that instantiation in your `initState` method in the stateful widget before you changed your code?

To create an AnimationController you need a state with a (Single)TickerProviderStateMixin. You can't do that within a stateless widget.

But you can use the GetX tools also in a stateful widget. Often, you don't need a stateful widget as GetX keeps the state outside of the widget. But in your case the animation has and needs a state for itself.

Comment: So you say there is no way keep using stateless widget + GetX doing this and I must tur my code back to use  stateful widget again?

Comment: a) If you want to use animations the way you intended, you need a stateful widget. However, you can still use (and it is useful!) GetX within that.
b) You could keep your stateless widget but you would have to tweak your animations a bit. What if you use AnimatedSwitcher or AnimatedOpacity etc? These are helpful tools that handle all your AnimationController etc stuff for you, keep your code simple - and stateless.

Comment: You are already using an AnimatedContainer: a widget that is animated but you don't have to care about an AnimationController etc. You give it a duration and curves - that's it.
Same applies to AnimatedOpacity or AnimatedSwitcher. You can give an AnimatedSwitcher even a transitionBuilder:  (Widget child,  Animation<double> animation) { return ScaleTransition(
                                              scale: animation, child: child);
                                        },
                                        child: ...)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. As I am a new learner and don't know much about Flutter, I added a new part of the original code to the EDIT part of my question. Please let me know should I just put this code inside my new code or I must do some other extra modifications?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can´t just put that code from a stateful widget into a stateless widget. "initState" is called in the life cycle of a stateful widget. What you do there, is to instantiate an AnimatedController, that has its own needs: you have to start it within a State and it needs a vsync object: A TickerProvider that will give your Animation the time.

Comment: However, take a step back: Why do you not want a stateful widget there? You want to centralize your state with a certain state management approach (GetX in your case). The idea is, not to have your state all over the app, but centralized, removed from the UI. That's good. But it does not mean that you have to only have stateless widgets. You are (normally) not interested in keeping track of the state of your animations. You want your business state and logic separated.

Comment: But it's OK to have a stateful widget handling animations, while at the same time, you still separate your business logic and state away from that. That would mean: You go back to your stateful widget and keep your animations, but still replace all your business logic and the state through using GetX (or the state management approach of your choice) within a stateful widget.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. But before that I tried to move `initState()` codes into a `GetXController with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin` class inside the `onInit()` method, that I had for authentication purposes and used an instance of it in my authentication screen(the code above), and it worked!